# Java Regex Find a valid mobile number from a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to find valid mobile number from a string:

- A valid mobile number starts with 923, or 03
- The length of the string after 923 or 03 is 9.
- There must not be any **digit** character before or after the mobile number.

**Sample Input**:
I have following sample input string:

```
Hello 03005119809 hey 030051119809 hey 23103005119809 923459590029 9234595902029 mobile923458590030has
```

**Expected Output**:

03005119809

923458590029

923458590030

**Actual Output with:** `[^0-9]923|03[0-9]{9}[^0-9]`

First Occurence: 03005119809

Second Occurence: 03005119809

Third occurence: 92

**Actual Output with:** `[^0-9][03|923][0-9]{9}`

First Occurence: 0300511980

Second Occurence: 0300511198

Third occurence: 2310300511

Fourth Occurence: 9234595900

Fifth Occurence: 9234595902

Comment: and you tagged this as Java because?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AshrafPurno I have tried a lot of regex patterns, and mentioned two of them in the end of my question

Comment: @Stultuske, I tagged java because, java has a slightly different regex format. Very minor differences though

Comment: @Stultuske I agree with OP, you should always tag the language too. Different languages supports different regex flavors, tagging language helps.

Comment: @AshrafPurno can you please remove your downvote now?

Comment: @Stultuske Can you please remove your downvote now?

Comment: @djaqeel no, since I didn't cast a downvote.

Comment: @dj aqeel downvote removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahul's answer helped me to cater most of the scenarios. But one scenario wasn't being handled. i.e. It didn't match a mobile number from following string:

> bla bla Mobile923458590029has bla bla

For that, I used following regex. I.e to extract a number starting with 923 or 03 having length of 12 or 11 characters surrounded with anything which is not a digit

```
(?<!\d)(?:03|923)\d{9}(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Below regex would help you as your requirement:

```
\b03\d{9}\b|\b923\d{9}\b
```

\b assert position at a word boundary.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vK1aL6/1)

Comment: Sir what does \b stand for?

Comment: You can write it as `\b(?:0|92)3\d{9}\b`.

Comment: \b description is putted in answer.

Comment: Is there any way we can modify the regex to include following scenario:
`mobile923458590029is` returns `923458590029`